# Indicator icons disappearing after screen lock after yakkety upgrade

Tags: unity, indicator, 16.10

After upgrade to yakkety, when I lock my screen and then unlock, some of the indicator icons (eg skype, and electron based apps) are replaced by the generic missing icon (the menus are still functional)

The behaviour is quite strange, since when I close one of the affected apps by clicking in the exit/quit from the indicator menu, or by manually killing it from the command line, the other icons return to normal.

I don't know if this could be a cause, but when upgrading the upgrade program faulted and I had to manually finish the upgrade using apt.

If anyone could help I'd be greatly grateful. It's really unpleasant to have that ugly lock style icons, and is not practical to restart one of those indicators after every lockout.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one.  I've posted this to the r/Ubuntu reddit, perhaps we'll see an answer come down the line!

Comment: See; https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1635625

Comment: thank you very much @JorgeCastro, confirmed and following too